# Error when returning interface with generic type

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am trying to return an object which should be an implementation of IClass with a generic type that is an implementation of IType.

```
public IClass<IType> createClass()
{
    return new ActualClass();
}
```

The actual class I want to return extends Class (abstract), with a generic type of ActualType:

```
public class ActualClass extends Class<ActualType>
```

The abstract Class object implements the IClass interface, and can have any type that extends IType

```
public abstract class Class<T extends IType> implements IClass<T>
```

The ActualType simply implements the IType interface

```
public final class ActualType implements IType
```

I get a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ActualClass to IClass" error on compilation. I can't understand why, since ActualClass implements IClass (indirectly via Class) and ActualType implements IType.

How can I rearrange this so it works? What have I done wrong or misunderstood?

Ideally I still want to have an interface IClass and IType, an abstract implementation Class, and then an ActualClass which extends the abstract Class and has a specific type  which has implemented IType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hierarchy of `ActualClass` is like this:

```
IClass<ActualType>
       ^
       |
Class<ActualType>
       ^
       |
   ActualClass
```

So, `IClass<ActualType>` is super type of `ActualClass`. But the return type of your method is `IClass<IType>`. Even though `IType` is super type of `ActualType`, `IClass<IType>` is not a super type of `IClass<ActualType>`, and thus it is also not super type of `ActualClass`.

So, either change the return type of method to `IClass<ActualType>`, or `IClass<? extends IType>`. The following should work:

```
public IClass<? extends IType> createClass() {
    return new ActualClass();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that does work. However putting <? extends IType> instead of <IType> throughout my code doesn't quite seem right (the result of that function is passed through various places). Am I being silly to worry about this. Another solution that seems to work is to change the abstract Class to:

    public abstract class Class<T extends IType> implements IClass<IType>

Is that also going to cause problems?

Answer (score 2):

Change the method signature of `createClass` to:

```
public IClass<? extends IType> createClass() {
    return new ActualClass();
}
```

The reason it doesn't compile is that [Generics in Java are not implicitly polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p), so you have to explicitly denote that the method would be able to return `IClass` parameterized by an unknown subset of `IType`